# Why is SO_RCVTIMEO ignored when applied to a recv() windows socket?

Tags: c, network-programming

I'd like the blocking recv() to abort if no data is read within 5 seconds.

Here's the code to create the socket `sock` and connect to a server

```
sock = WSASocket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, 0, 0, 0 );
WSAConnect( sock, ptr->ai_addr, sizeof ( struct addrinfo ), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL )
```

Before calling recv(), the function setsockopt() is called successfully. However, the recv() remains blocked indefinitely?

```
DWORD timeout = 5 * 1000;

if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("failed setting socket option GLE %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(sock);
    return INVALID_SOCKET;
}

...
cbRead = recv ( sock, ( CHAR * ) pTemp, cbRemaining, 0 );
...
```

The only workaround I've found is the following code which calls recv() when there's no  socket error or timeout

```
fd_set fds;
FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(sock, &fds);

struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 5;
tv.tv_usec = 0;

int ret = select(0, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR || ret == 0) {
    printf("TIMEOUT detected on socket=%d ERROR=%d\n", s, ret);
    return FALSE;
}

...
cbRead = recv ( sock, ( CHAR * ) pTemp, cbRemaining, 0 );
...
```

**Question**

Is there a reason why using `SO_RCVTIMEO` is ignored? I'd prefer setting the timeout directly on the socket via `setsockopt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the detailed Winsock docs for `SO_RCVTIMEO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/sol-socket-socket-options),

> If the socket is created using the `WSASocket` function, then the *dwFlags* parameter must have the `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` attribute set for the timeout to function properly. Otherwise the timeout never takes effect.

The `WSASocket()` call you show does not specify `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` among the flags, so your observation that the receive timeout you specify does not take effect is consistent with the documentation.

Note also that [the docs for `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsasocketa#parameters) say, among other things,

> Most sockets should be created with this flag set.

These details are mostly specific to Winsock.  As far as I am aware, POSIX sockets do not have or need an analog of `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`.

Comment: Wow...it works now! I spent several hours debugging this! As you noted, add the flag to WSASocket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, 0, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED). Thank you!